# net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error on ajax clock

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, console, console.log

I have an ajax php clock set up and for some reason it's giving me thousands of net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES errors in my console.

What's the reason behind this?

Code that calls out the clock function

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    setInterval(function(){   
        $(".clock").load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/melbourne.php');;
    });
}(), 1000);
```

Melbourne.php

```
<?php  

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');

echo $date = date('H:i:s');

?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load resource under Chrome! Not work ajax currently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939913/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome-not-work-ajax-currently)

Comment: Yes and no. I can understand now why it happens but I can't understand the fix for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misplaced the `setInterval` delay. You provided it to the `$(document).ready()`... Which is probably discarding it. So the interval having no delay, it is sending some requests one after the other non-stop.

Look at the difference below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $(".clock").load('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/melbourne.php');;
  },1000);
});
```

Also, be careful with the parenthesis after a function expression.

This is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE): `<--` Read that!

```
function something(){
  // .. some code
}()
```

Event handlers expect a function expression, so they can execute it at a later time. If you provide an IIFE, the event handler will receive the result of the function execution...

Answer (score 0):

You are making AJAX calls to the Melbourne.php file every second, thus establishing a connection and killing it every second. This uses up plenty of resources and as the calls increase, the request threshold is met depending on what browser you are using.

I would suggest you use websockets (https://socket.io/docs/v4/) to request for data from melbourne.php as communication is in full duplex mode and connection is made only once.